# How to include cv.imread() when building opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

I cloned the OpenCV Git repository: `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`
and did not change anything.

Then I followed the build `opencv.js` documentation on OpenCV step by step
https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html
and successfully built the `opencv.js` and `tests` with the command

> `python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --build_test`

Then I opened with a live server the created `test.html` and saw that all tests were successful: `"581 assertions of 581 passed, 0 failed."`

But when I insert the built `opencv.js` between the `<script> </script>` tags and use it, it still works except for `cv.imread()`. I get the error message: `

> "Uncaught TypeError: cv.imread is not a function".`

Here is the code block:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let matrix = cv.imread("canvas");
```

Then I used the official opencv.js and imread() worked. The problem is, however, that opencv.js is 7.7 mb in size, because it includes most of OpenCV's capabilities and I only need some core and image processing functions.

How can imread() be included in the build? I could not find a solution so far. I only found the build Whitelist: it is in the OpenCV repository and has the name opencv_js.config.py and includes the following. Any idea how imread() can be included in the build? Because the OpenCV JavaScript documentation uses imread() in pretty much every example, there should be an easy way to include it.

```
# Classes and methods whitelist

core = {
    '': [
        'absdiff', 'add', 'addWeighted', 'bitwise_and', 'bitwise_not', 'bitwise_or', 'bitwise_xor', 'cartToPolar',
        'compare', 'convertScaleAbs', 'copyMakeBorder', 'countNonZero', 'determinant', 'dft', 'divide', 'eigen',
        'exp', 'flip', 'getOptimalDFTSize','gemm', 'hconcat', 'inRange', 'invert', 'kmeans', 'log', 'magnitude',
        'max', 'mean', 'meanStdDev', 'merge', 'min', 'minMaxLoc', 'mixChannels', 'multiply', 'norm', 'normalize',
        'perspectiveTransform', 'polarToCart', 'pow', 'randn', 'randu', 'reduce', 'repeat', 'rotate', 'setIdentity', 'setRNGSeed',
        'solve', 'solvePoly', 'split', 'sqrt', 'subtract', 'trace', 'transform', 'transpose', 'vconcat',
        'setLogLevel', 'getLogLevel',
    ],
    'Algorithm': [],
}

imgproc = {'': ['Canny', 'GaussianBlur', 'Laplacian', 'HoughLines', 'HoughLinesP', 'HoughCircles', 'Scharr','Sobel', \
                'adaptiveThreshold','approxPolyDP','arcLength','bilateralFilter','blur','boundingRect','boxFilter',\
                'calcBackProject','calcHist','circle','compareHist','connectedComponents','connectedComponentsWithStats', \
                'contourArea', 'convexHull', 'convexityDefects', 'cornerHarris','cornerMinEigenVal','createCLAHE', \
                'createLineSegmentDetector','cvtColor','demosaicing','dilate', 'distanceTransform','distanceTransformWithLabels', \
                'drawContours','ellipse','ellipse2Poly','equalizeHist','erode', 'filter2D', 'findContours','fitEllipse', \
                'fitLine', 'floodFill','getAffineTransform', 'getPerspectiveTransform', 'getRotationMatrix2D', 'getStructuringElement', \
                'goodFeaturesToTrack','grabCut','initUndistortRectifyMap', 'integral','integral2', 'isContourConvex', 'line', \
                'matchShapes', 'matchTemplate','medianBlur', 'minAreaRect', 'minEnclosingCircle', 'moments', 'morphologyEx', \
                'pointPolygonTest', 'putText','pyrDown','pyrUp','rectangle','remap', 'resize','sepFilter2D','threshold', \
                'undistort','warpAffine','warpPerspective','warpPolar','watershed', \
                'fillPoly', 'fillConvexPoly', 'polylines',
    ],
    'CLAHE': ['apply', 'collectGarbage', 'getClipLimit', 'getTilesGridSize', 'setClipLimit', 'setTilesGridSize'],
    'segmentation_IntelligentScissorsMB': [
        'IntelligentScissorsMB',
        'setWeights',
        'setGradientMagnitudeMaxLimit',
        'setEdgeFeatureZeroCrossingParameters',
        'setEdgeFeatureCannyParameters',
        'applyImage',
        'applyImageFeatures',
        'buildMap',
        'getContour'
    ],
}

objdetect = {'': ['groupRectangles'],
             'HOGDescriptor': ['load', 'HOGDescriptor', 'getDefaultPeopleDetector', 'getDaimlerPeopleDetector', 'setSVMDetector', 'detectMultiScale'],
             'CascadeClassifier': ['load', 'detectMultiScale2', 'CascadeClassifier', 'detectMultiScale3', 'empty', 'detectMultiScale'],
             'QRCodeDetector': ['QRCodeDetector', 'decode', 'decodeCurved', 'detect', 'detectAndDecode', 'detectMulti', 'setEpsX', 'setEpsY']}

video = {'': ['CamShift', 'calcOpticalFlowFarneback', 'calcOpticalFlowPyrLK', 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2', \
             'findTransformECC', 'meanShift'],
         'BackgroundSubtractorMOG2': ['BackgroundSubtractorMOG2', 'apply'],
         'BackgroundSubtractor': ['apply', 'getBackgroundImage']}

dnn = {'dnn_Net': ['setInput', 'forward'],
       '': ['readNetFromCaffe', 'readNetFromTensorflow', 'readNetFromTorch', 'readNetFromDarknet',
            'readNetFromONNX', 'readNet', 'blobFromImage']}

features2d = {'Feature2D': ['detect', 'compute', 'detectAndCompute', 'descriptorSize', 'descriptorType', 'defaultNorm', 'empty', 'getDefaultName'],
              'BRISK': ['create', 'getDefaultName'],
              'ORB': ['create', 'setMaxFeatures', 'setScaleFactor', 'setNLevels', 'setEdgeThreshold', 'setFirstLevel', 'setWTA_K', 'setScoreType', 'setPatchSize', 'getFastThreshold', 'getDefaultName'],
              'MSER': ['create', 'detectRegions', 'setDelta', 'getDelta', 'setMinArea', 'getMinArea', 'setMaxArea', 'getMaxArea', 'setPass2Only', 'getPass2Only', 'getDefaultName'],
              'FastFeatureDetector': ['create', 'setThreshold', 'getThreshold', 'setNonmaxSuppression', 'getNonmaxSuppression', 'setType', 'getType', 'getDefaultName'],
              'AgastFeatureDetector': ['create', 'setThreshold', 'getThreshold', 'setNonmaxSuppression', 'getNonmaxSuppression', 'setType', 'getType', 'getDefaultName'],
              'GFTTDetector': ['create', 'setMaxFeatures', 'getMaxFeatures', 'setQualityLevel', 'getQualityLevel', 'setMinDistance', 'getMinDistance', 'setBlockSize', 'getBlockSize', 'setHarrisDetector', 'getHarrisDetector', 'setK', 'getK', 'getDefaultName'],
              # 'SimpleBlobDetector': ['create'],
              'KAZE': ['create', 'setExtended', 'getExtended', 'setUpright', 'getUpright', 'setThreshold', 'getThreshold', 'setNOctaves', 'getNOctaves', 'setNOctaveLayers', 'getNOctaveLayers', 'setDiffusivity', 'getDiffusivity', 'getDefaultName'],
              'AKAZE': ['create', 'setDescriptorType', 'getDescriptorType', 'setDescriptorSize', 'getDescriptorSize', 'setDescriptorChannels', 'getDescriptorChannels', 'setThreshold', 'getThreshold', 'setNOctaves', 'getNOctaves', 'setNOctaveLayers', 'getNOctaveLayers', 'setDiffusivity', 'getDiffusivity', 'getDefaultName'],
              'DescriptorMatcher': ['add', 'clear', 'empty', 'isMaskSupported', 'train', 'match', 'knnMatch', 'radiusMatch', 'clone', 'create'],
              'BFMatcher': ['isMaskSupported', 'create'],
              '': ['drawKeypoints', 'drawMatches', 'drawMatchesKnn']}

photo = {'': ['createAlignMTB', 'createCalibrateDebevec', 'createCalibrateRobertson', \
              'createMergeDebevec', 'createMergeMertens', 'createMergeRobertson', \
              'createTonemapDrago', 'createTonemapMantiuk', 'createTonemapReinhard', 'inpaint'],
        'CalibrateCRF': ['process'],
        'AlignMTB' : ['calculateShift', 'shiftMat', 'computeBitmaps', 'getMaxBits', 'setMaxBits', \
                      'getExcludeRange', 'setExcludeRange', 'getCut', 'setCut'],
        'CalibrateDebevec' : ['getLambda', 'setLambda', 'getSamples', 'setSamples', 'getRandom', 'setRandom'],
        'CalibrateRobertson' : ['getMaxIter', 'setMaxIter', 'getThreshold', 'setThreshold', 'getRadiance'],
        'MergeExposures' : ['process'],
        'MergeDebevec' : ['process'],
        'MergeMertens' : ['process', 'getContrastWeight', 'setContrastWeight', 'getSaturationWeight', \
                          'setSaturationWeight', 'getExposureWeight', 'setExposureWeight'],
        'MergeRobertson' : ['process'],
        'Tonemap' : ['process' , 'getGamma', 'setGamma'],
        'TonemapDrago' : ['getSaturation', 'setSaturation', 'getBias', 'setBias', \
                          'getSigmaColor', 'setSigmaColor', 'getSigmaSpace','setSigmaSpace'],
        'TonemapMantiuk' : ['getScale', 'setScale', 'getSaturation', 'setSaturation'],
        'TonemapReinhard' : ['getIntensity', 'setIntensity', 'getLightAdaptation', 'setLightAdaptation', \
                             'getColorAdaptation', 'setColorAdaptation']
        }

aruco = {'': ['detectMarkers', 'drawDetectedMarkers', 'drawAxis', 'estimatePoseSingleMarkers', 'estimatePoseBoard', 'estimatePoseCharucoBoard', 'interpolateCornersCharuco', 'drawDetectedCornersCharuco'],
        'aruco_Dictionary': ['get', 'drawMarker'],
        'aruco_Board': ['create'],
        'aruco_GridBoard': ['create', 'draw'],
        'aruco_CharucoBoard': ['create', 'draw'],
        'aruco_DetectorParameters': ['create']
        }

calib3d = {'': ['findHomography', 'calibrateCameraExtended', 'drawFrameAxes', 'estimateAffine2D', \
                'getDefaultNewCameraMatrix', 'initUndistortRectifyMap', 'Rodrigues', \
                'solvePnP', 'solvePnPRansac', 'solvePnPRefineLM']}


white_list = makeWhiteList([core, imgproc, objdetect, video, dnn, features2d, photo, aruco, calib3d])
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used emscripten to compile opencv from source and it finished without any error, but when I tried to load it in browser, it didn't work at all. Problem was solved with an older version of emscripten.

```
git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git
cd emsdk/
./emsdk install 1.39.15
./emsdk activate 1.39.15
source ./emsdk_env.sh
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
emcmake python ./opencv/platforms/js/build_js.py build_wasm --build_wasm
```

I went through all the newer versions but the 1.39.15 is the latest one what worked for me. This way I reduced the opencv.js file until 1.7MB.

Comment: It also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why cv.imread() can not be used from your self-build `opencv.js` is because it return `cv.ready`, which is a Promise (check your self-build `opencv.js`, line:34). However, the offical build opencv.js return cv (https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/opencv.js ). So if you follow the old document to use cv with your self-bould `opencv.js`, you will get error.

As mentioned in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21580
There are two ways to fix this problem.

1. Adopt the Promise usage, try reset cv right after opencv.js is loaded.

```
<script src="js/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();" type="text/javascript"></script>
async function onOpenCvReady() { window.cv = await window.cv }
```

2. Or you can keep the original usage, but you have to modify `opencv.js`:

modify opencv.js line:34

`return cv.ready`

to

`return cv`

and then use cv after `onRuntimeInitialize` is called.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same problem as well. It looks like the opencv.js documentation hasn't been updated for newer versions of the emscripten Module API (or this is just something I am doing differently than the OpenCV docs and it happens to work).

As shown in [the embind docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html) you can use the `onRuntimeInitialized` function to detect when the WASM module has finished loading, and thereafter access its exported functions via the `Module` object. This is how I was able to use `opencv.js` including `cv.imread`:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello OpenCV.js</h1>
    <div>
      <div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var Module = {
        onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
          console.log(Module.imread)
          const cv = Module;

          let fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

          fileInput.onchange = (e) => {
            const image = new Image();

            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

            image.onload = ()  => {
              const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
              const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

              canvas.height = image.height;
              canvas.width = image.width;

              context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
              const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);

              const cvImage = cv.imread("canvas");
              const mean = cv.mean(cvImage)
              console.log(`Mean: ${mean[0]}, ${mean[1]}, ${mean[2]}`)
            }
          };
        }
      };
    </script>
    <script src="opencv.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Important:** Make sure that you don't compile the OpenCV `imcodecs` module, as the browser version of `imread` will be overwritten by the C++ version. The browser implementation (defined in `opencv/modules/js/src/helpers.js`) loads images from the browser, whereas the C++ version loads them from files.

Bear in mind that I am just starting out with WASM, emscripten and JavaScript, so excuse any potential misuse of terminology please.
And if I am doing something wrong or badly, I would be more than happy for some feedback as well.